# How to create shortcut for Android Development Tools in Delphi 10.4 Sydney

Tags: android, delphi

I have installed Delphi 10.4 Sydney with installed Android SDKs. I don't know which of my collegues installed it, but there it is - there are files and folders like

```
C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\21.0\CatalogRepository\AndroidSDK-2525-21.0.38860.1461\tools
```

That indicates that Andorid SDKs or even the full Android Development Tools has have been installed using the standard installer or https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Installing_the_Android_Development_Tools_Manually But I don't see shortcut to `Android Development Tools` in start menu (under 'Embarcader RAD Studio 10.4') and I cannot find the relevant exe or bat file to which I can point my shortcut if I wanted to create the shortcut myself.

Which is the main file for Android Development Tools for Delphi 10.4 Sydney (or its relatives).

*Question complemented*: Here is one thing that I expect from 'Android Development Tools': I can click on `C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\21.0\CatalogRepository\AndroidSDK-2525-21.0.38860.1461\tools\android.bat` file and the `Android SDK Manager` opens in which I can indicate that I want e.g. install `Google Play APK Expansion library` and install it from this SDK manager. But I have no shortcut to access normally this SDK manager from Delphi. My guess is - if I had completed the correct installation of the Android Development Tools than I would have such shortcut to Android SDK manager in Start Menu or in Delphi IDE. It is quite possible, that other features there would be as well about which I have no even any idea now.

*Question complemented 2*: and, of course, my big concern is also how to start Android emulator from Delphi IDE and how to run app in it. I guess, it would be easy and it could be done from some IDE shortcut or menu item if only the Android Development Tools were present.

Comment: What do you mean by "Android Development Tools"? What tool are you looking for?

Comment: I added short example about access of Android SDK Manager - I expect some shortcut from Delphi. The fact that I have no one may indicate the incomplete/incorrect installation of my Android Development Tools.

Comment: No. Delphi is not part of the Android SDK. Delphi is not like Android Studio, it is a separate executable that allows development for multiple platforms, not just Android. The shortcut for Delphi 10.4 is typically `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\21.0\bin\bds.exe" -pDelphi`